# Using eraser tool to split up an object along the path created with the pen tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

Where the pink line is (path drawn with a pen tool) is where I want the light blue object to be split up. I am using the eraser tool to do this but using the shift key to cut straight only allows for 45 and 90 degree cuts.

I've read advice where people say to "Use the Pen Tool to make a line and Stroke with the Eraser." That sounds like what I need to do here but I don't understand exactly how to do that--if anyone has a link to a video or can explain it step by step to me I would so appreciate it!

Or if you have a better suggestion for what I'm trying to achieve that works too.

[image]

Comment: Instructions are for photoshop. Why not just storke the line expand and use pathfinder to subtract that?

Comment: The eraser tool in Illustrator is not the same as the eraser tool in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eraser tool in Illustrator doesn't work like the eraser tool in Photoshop. It won't work for this. I would use the Shape Builder tool instead.

1. Type some text, and do *Type > Create outlines*
2. Open the Pathfinder and hit the *Unite" button.
3. Draw a shape around the bottom half of the text using the Pen Tool, with no fill, and a stroke you can see.
4. Select both the text and the rectangle
5. Use the Shape Builder tool. Click on all the pieces of the text you want to keep inside the rectangle, and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete the leftover pieces.
6. Select all the bottom pieces of text, remove the stroke, and add a fill.

Example

[image]

Comment: Perfect this solved my problem--thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach...

1. Select your pink pen stroke and Object> Expand- just click OK in the dialog
2. Select both the expanded Pen path and the shape you want to cut (make sure it is  a filled path or outlined text and not just a path with a stroke)
3. Go to the Pathfinder Panel and click Minus Front

This will cut the shape into separate parts.

[image]